# mongo group by multiple times

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Lets asume I have this set of data:

```
{ ValidFrom: "2019-03-25T16:01:55.714+0000", ValidTo: "2019-03-25T16:01:55.714+0000" },    
{ ValidFrom: "2019-03-26T16:01:55.714+0000", ValidTo: "2019-03-25T16:01:55.714+0000" },    
{ ValidFrom: "2019-03-25T16:01:55.714+0000", ValidTo: "2019-03-27T16:01:55.714+0000" }
```

I would like to see this result with one query:

```
{ "Day": "2019-03-25", ValidFromCount: 2, ValidToCount: 2 },    
{ "Day": "2019-03-26", ValidFromCount: 1, ValidToCount: 0 },    
{ "Day": "2019-03-27", ValidFromCount: 0, ValidToCount: 1 }
```

Currently I wrote this aggregation but I am stuck now:

```
 {
     $addFields: {
            ValidFromDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$ValidFrom" } },
            ValidUntilDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$ValidUntil" } }
     }
 },
 {
     $group : {
        _id: { FromDate: '$ValidFromDay', ToDate: '$ValidUntilDay' },
        Count: { "$sum": 1 },
     }
 }, 
 {
     $group : {
        _id: null,
        FromDates: { "$addToSet": { "Date": "$_id.FromDate", "FromCount": { "$sum": "$Count" } } },
        ToDate: { "$addToSet": { "Date": "$_id.ToDate", "UntilCount": "$Count" } }
     }
 }
```

Is it possible to produce the results I am looking for in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an array of 2 fields, not just 2 fields. It will let you to unwind it and count by date:

```
{
     $addFields: {
            boundary: [
                { day: {$dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$ValidFrom" } }, from: 1 },
                { day: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$ValidTo" } } , to: 1 }
                ]
     }
},
{
    $unwind: "$boundary"
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$boundary.day",
        ValidFromCount: {$sum: "$boundary.from"},
        ValidToCount: {$sum: "$boundary.to"},
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want. There are three stages to the pipeline. A`$project` that constructs a separate day, month and year fields.

```
> projector
{
    "$project" : {
        "day" : {
            "$dayOfMonth" : "$ValidFrom"
        },
        "month" : {
            "$month" : "$ValidFrom"
        },
        "year" : {
            "$year" : "$ValidFrom"
        },
        "ValidFrom" : 1
    }
}
```

Then a `$group` to create the totals and count them by individual day by using an `_id` of `{year, month, day}`.

```
> grouper
{
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : {
            "year" : "$year",
            "month" : "$month",
            "day" : "$day"
        },
        "ValidFromCount" : {
            "$sum" : 1
        },
        "ValidToCount" : {
            "$sum" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, a projection to eliminate the spurious fields and also get the `Day` field into the format you want.

```
> converter
{
    "$project" : {
        "_id" : 0,
        "Day" : {
            "$concat" : [
                {
                    "$toString" : "$_id.year"
                },
                "-",
                {
                    "$toString" : "$_id.month"
                },
                "-",
                {
                    "$toString" : "$_id.day"
                }
            ]
        },
        "ValidFromCount" : 1,
        "ValidToCount" : 1
    }
}
```

to run just execute (I created your data in collection so2):

```
> db.so2.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ca75adfd1a64a2919883a8d"), "ValidFrom" : "2019-03-25T16:01:55.714+0000", "ValidTo" : "2019-03-25T16:01:55.714+0000" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ca75adfd1a64a2919883a8e"), "ValidFrom" : "2019-03-26T16:01:55.714+0000", "ValidTo" : "2019-03-25T16:01:55.714+0000" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ca75adfd1a64a2919883a8f"), "ValidFrom" : "2019-03-25T16:01:55.714+0000", "ValidTo" : "2019-03-27T16:01:55.714+0000" }
>
> db.so3.aggregate([projector,grouper,converter])
{ "ValidFromCount" : 1, "ValidToCount" : 1, "Day" : "2019-3-26" }
{ "ValidFromCount" : 2, "ValidToCount" : 2, "Day" : "2019-3-25" }
>
```

I'm not sure if the test data you supplied is correct because the second document appears to go back in time so the `ValidTo` is before the `ValidFrom`.